# Run function on Flask server every x seconds to update Redis cache without clients making separate calls

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask, redis

I currently have a flask app that makes a call to S3 as well as an external API with the following structure before rendering the data in javascript:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,make_response
from flask import request
import requests
import requests_cache 
import redis
from boto3.session import Session
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test')
def test1():
    bucket_root = 'testbucket'

    session = Session(
        aws_access_key_id='s3_key',
        aws_secret_access_key='s3_secret_key')
    s3 = session.resource('s3')

    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_root)

    testvalues = json.dumps(s3.Object(bucket_root,'all1.json').get()['Body'].read())

    r = requests.get(api_link)

    return render_template('test_html.html',json_s3_test_response=r.content,
                        limit=limit, testvalues=testvalues)

@app.route('/test2')
def test2():
    bucket_root = 'testbucket'

    session = Session(
        aws_access_key_id='s3_key',
        aws_secret_access_key='s3_secret_key')
    s3 = session.resource('s3')

    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_root)

    testvalues = json.dumps(s3.Object(bucket_root,'all2.json').get()['Body'].read())

    r = requests.get(api_link)

    return render_template('test_html.html',json_s3_test_response=r.content,
                        limit=limit, testvalues=testvalues)

@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_error(error):
    return "500 error"

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return "404 error",404

@app.errorhandler(400)
def custom400(error):
    return "400 error",400

//catch all?
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def all_exception_handler(error):
    return 'error', 500
```

Obviously I have a lot of inefficiencies here, but my main question is:

To me it seems like I'm calling S3 and the external API for each client, every time they refresh the page. This increases the chance for the app to crash due to timeouts (and my poor error handling) and diminishes performance. I would like to resolve this by periodically caching the S3 results (say every 10 mins) into a local redis server (already set up and running) as well as just pinging the external API just once from the server every few seconds before passing it onto ALL clients.

I have code that can store the data into redis every 10 mins in a regular python script, however, I'm not sure where to place this within the flask server? Do I put it as it's own function or keep the call to redis in the @app.route()?

Thank you everyone for your time and effort. Any help would be appreciated! I'm new to flask so some of this has been confusing.

Comment: you have a lot of questions for 1 question =). please divide your post to address each individually =)

Comment: sorry @glls I'm not sure how to break this up exactly as it's partially me asking alternatives... I'll try though! Is it fair to keep the bulk and adjust the final questions?